# Using an object as a DataGridViewRow

Tags: vb.net, object, inheritance, datagridview

Lets say I have a Person class with a name, telephone, email and a bool called selected.
The persons are generated through a semi colon separated text file. 
I loop the file and get the values for each person. What is the best practice for displaying them in a DataGridView with the columns "use" (checkbox for "selected"), "name", and "email"? (note that I'm leaving the telephone out)
As it is now, i have a function called MakeDataGridRow in the Person class which i use something like this:

```
For each line blah blah StreamReader(filename) blah...
    Dim P as New Person(line.split(";"))
    MyDataGridview.Rows.Add(P.MakeDataGridRow)
End For
```

This works, but this is not really good since when I wanna do something with the list, I have to loop the list and generate a new Person for every checked row, right? And in this case I can't get the telephone number since it's not in the list. I could save them in a list of persons (in the file read loop) and check every selected row against this list to get the telephone, but i don't like this solution.

The nice solution would be if the Person class inherits DataGridViewRow so that when i loop my rows I can use the allready created Persons to check the phone number. How do i do this?

some thing like:

```
Public Class Person
    Inherits DataGridViewRow

    Public Name As String
    Public Telephone as String
    Public Email As String
    Public Selected As Boolean

    Public Sub New(ByVal Values As String())
        Name = Values(0)
        Telephone = Values(1)
        Email = Values(2)
        Selected = True
    End Sub
End Class
```

How can i display this class as a row in a DataGridView so that I later, when I do something with the persons, I can do something more like

```
For Each P as Person In MyDataGridView.Rows
    If P.Selected Then
        MsgBox(P.Name & ", telephone: " & P.Telephone)
    End If
End For
```

I think you understand what I'm trying to achieve, any suggestions?

Comment: put the Persons in a List(of Person) then use it as a datasource for the DGV.  You might have to make those Fields into Properties in order to map Properties to Columns.  The data will be in the List<T>, so you can iterate it etc, and the DGV will simply read it to display the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Think of them as two separate objects. Don't inherit your Person class from the DataGridViewRow.

A. Remove the `Inherits DataGridViewRow` from your Person class defination.

B. In your Person class, convert all fields into properties. Depending in what version of .net you are using, it would be just sufficient to add the `Property` keyword to the declaration, or you may have to put the full property definition.

C. Now it can be databound to the grid easily. (you can specify fixed columns. I just auto-generated in this example)

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' create a new list of Persons. THis will act as datasource for the gridview.
    Dim personsList As New List(Of Person)

    ' fill data into the list.  
    ' *I skip the implementation of this part, you already have that code* 

    ' bind the persons list to the Grid view.
    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True
    DataGridView1.DataSource = personsList

    ' hide unwanted columns
    DataGridView1.Columns("Email").Visible = False
End Sub
```

D. And now you can easily get your person object and anything from it. e.g. To get phone number:

```
Private Function GetPhoneNumber(ByVal rowNumber As Integer) As String
    Return DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(rowNumber).DataBoundItem, Person).Telephone
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! works perfect! A stupid question tho, how can i tell the datagridview to hide some of the values? Or, how can i define like four columns and then tell the Person class (?) which value goes into what column? edit: a link is helpful eough ;)

Comment: You mean you want to define the columns in the DataGridView?

Comment: Exactly, the person actually have 20 values, but i just want to show three or four of them in my grid.

Comment: @gubbfett once you bind your dgv to your personlist you can choose the fields you want to show in its properties. just set AutoGenerateColumns = False

Comment: You can either set `AutoGenerateColumns = False`, and specify the columns manually, either from the properties window or from code. The other way is to keep `AutoGenerateColumns = True`, and just hide the unwanted columns. I just updated my answer above.

Comment: Yea, I found how to do that. Worked great. The only thing that does not work is that i can't sort the grid view now. Any ideas why? That is, whan i started to use the list as bidning, the grid is not sortable. :)

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting from `DataGridViewRow` doesn't give you any real benefit. I think the best solution would be to create a `List` of `Person`, with all the data you get from your CSV file.

Then you bind your list to your DataGridView like

```
MyDataGridView.BindingSource = MyListPersons
```

When you want to display your numbers just loop your selected rows, use `CType` to get the underlying object (a `Person` object) and display your phone.

This converts a dgv row into a Person object

```
    Dim p As Person = CType(row.DataBoundItem, Person)
    If p IsNot Nothing Then
        MsgBox(p.Name & ", telephone: " & p.Telephone)
    End If
```

Comment: Ok, cool. Because I'm lazy I'll ask directly; For letting the DataGridView understad what value that will be in which column, I guess I can name the columns as the same values as the person? Or how do i say "show Person.Telephone in the column named 'tel'"?

Comment: @gubbfett when your dgv datasource is linked to your Person class (you need to add the datasource using the designer first), you can add the columns you need and you'll choose them from a list of Person properties. this is the great thing of the bound columns